# Keyboard hook problems

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, hook

I'm learning windows hooking, and i wrote this code:

Dll:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK CBTFrenk(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    FILE *fp = fopen ("F:\\log.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fp, "CALLED!");
    fclose(fp);
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);      }
```

app:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    char fine;
    HINSTANCE hdll = LoadLibrary((LPCTSTR) L"F:\\Progetti\\CBT_Hook\\Debug\\DllForHook.dll");
    wprintf(L"%d\n", GetLastError());
    HOOKPROC pfunc = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hdll, "_CBTFrenk@12");
    wprintf(L"%d\n", GetLastError());
    HHOOK handleToAHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, pfunc, hdll, 0);
    wprintf(L"%d\n", GetLastError());
    scanf("%d", &fine);

    return 0;
}
```

The dll and the hook procedure are loaded without error, but the function do nothing when i press the key of my keyboard. Why? If i change WH_KEYBOARD with WH_CBT, it's work... what's the reason? And what's the difference between WH_KEYBOARD and WH_KEYBOARD_LL?

Thanks for the collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

LowlevelKeyboardProc is performed in the context of the calling process, so the process need a message loop as write in msdn library.